# How do i get Facebook shop working in Canada

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ads-api, commerce

I have not been able to use Facebook shop in Canada! I have tried outsourcing it hoping  that could be the solution but it is not still working. has there been anyone who has been able to use Facebook Shop in Canada?

Comment: _"Any solution?"_ - to what actual problem? It is currently very unclear what you are even talking about here, and "doesn't work" is not a useful problem description. Please go read [ask], and then try and edit your question to provide us with some more, actually useful information about what the problem here _is_ to begin with.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.